# How HtmlCleaner handles Iframes in webpage

Tags: java, htmlcleaner

I want to understand how HtmlCleaner handles Iframes when cleaning raw html to produce valid xml output. One example of a page with iframes is [this ebay product page](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/MENS-FIRETRAP-GREY-MARL-VISION-SHIRT-BNWT-/200624549025?_trksid=p4340.m263&_trkparms=algo=DLSL%252BSIC&its=I&itu=UCI%252BIA%252BUA%252BFICS%252BUFI%252BDDSIC&otn=8&pmod=290475488497%252B290475488497&po=&ps=63&clkid=1820041698587663447&_qi=RTM637057#ht_1201wt_1125).

When I print the output of HtmlCleaner for this page, I find that some iframe tags are intact while others are missing. One of the missing iframes is the iframe with id="d". It contains the product description and its body has been merged into the main page.

The XML Output of html cleaner: http://pastebin.com/03f9gtdC

Could anyone kindly look at it, or suggest some better HTML parsing library which is able to handle iframes gracefully. That library should be able to support XPath evaluation.